# JMustache credit is mentioned as Butterknife

Tags: bug, android-app

Go to About page, and scroll down to bottom. There are two Butterknife credits mentioned, but the later is actually JMustache.

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: motorola
- Device Model: XT1095

  - OS Version: 6.0 (20)

Comment: Yeah, and the year is also still 2015, even though there were few new versions during 2016. (Which is a pleasant surprise - I don't think there will be any further versions or any bug fix in 2016)